# Running different github workflow actions on the basis of conditions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow in which I want to use different custom actions based on some conditions of say environment variable. I am able to add condition within the action code and create the custom action as workaround, but to keep it clean wanted to know if there is better way/best practice to conditionally call some a workflow action.

```
name: Dummy Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Check environment variable
        run: |
          if [ "$TEST_ENV_VAR" = "true" ]; then
            echo "Environment variable is true"
            uses: actions/checkout@v2   <<--------------  like this        
          else
            echo "Environment variable is not true"
            exit 0
          fi
```

Comment: Use the if Expressions. This is then only executed if `if` is true. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-expression-in-an-if-conditional